# Can't change backgroundColor for specific candles in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to change the background for specific candles in my candlestick chart.

What i want is to be able to specify the background color of each candle instead of only being limited to the whole dataset.

The declaration of the chart:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'candlestick',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'CHRT - Chart.js Corporation',
            data: barData,
        }],
    },
});
```

The barData interface i want to use (i added backgroundColor):

```
{
        x: date.valueOf(),
        o: open,
        h: high,
        l: low,
        c: close,
        backgroundColor: "yellow"
}
```

The CandleStick Element class:

```
class CandlestickElement extends FinancialElement {
    draw(ctx) {
        const me = this;
        console.log(me)
        const {x, open, high, low, close} = me;
        let borderColors = me.borderColor;
        if (typeof borderColors === 'string') {
            borderColors = {
                up: borderColors,
                down: borderColors,
                unchanged: borderColors
            };
        }

        let borderColor;
        if (close < open) {
            borderColor = helpers.valueOrDefault(borderColors ? borderColors.up : undefined, globalOpts$1.elements.candlestick.borderColor);
            ctx.fillStyle = helpers.valueOrDefault(me.color ? me.color.up : undefined, globalOpts$1.elements.candlestick.color.up);
        } else if (close > open) {
            borderColor = helpers.valueOrDefault(borderColors ? borderColors.down : undefined, globalOpts$1.elements.candlestick.borderColor);
            ctx.fillStyle = helpers.valueOrDefault(me.color ? me.color.down : undefined, globalOpts$1.elements.candlestick.color.down);
        } else {
            borderColor = helpers.valueOrDefault(borderColors ? borderColors.unchanged : undefined, globalOpts$1.elements.candlestick.borderColor);
            ctx.fillStyle = helpers.valueOrDefault(me.color ? me.color.unchanged : undefined, globalOpts$1.elements.candlestick.color.unchanged);
        }
        ctx.lineWidth = helpers.valueOrDefault(me.borderWidth, globalOpts$1.elements.candlestick.borderWidth);
        ctx.strokeStyle = helpers.valueOrDefault(borderColor, globalOpts$1.elements.candlestick.borderColor);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, high);
        ctx.lineTo(x, Math.min(open, close));
        ctx.moveTo(x, low);
        ctx.lineTo(x, Math.max(open, close));
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillRect(x - me.width / 2, close, me.width, open - close);
        ctx.strokeRect(x - me.width / 2, close, me.width, open - close);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    }
```

An example candle:
[image: 1]